# Correct usage of the term 'gravity'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If I want to make clear that one object is being affected by the gravity of another object, for example the Earth and the moon.

Would I say:

> The moon has *a gravity*, just as all mass does.

or, would I say:

> The moon has *gravity*, just as all mass does.

Comment: Generally one speaks of a _gravitational field_ surrounding any massive object; but _gravity_ itself is like _force, motion, mass,_ and many other physical concepts -- an abstract (and therefore mass) noun.

Comment: This seems like a very clumsy sentence. Perhaps you should consider rewriting whatever it is you're trying to say so that you can avoid its usage.

Comment: Rephrasing the sentence as `The moon, like all mass, has gravity.` might make it sound more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is correct.  Rarely would you ever put 'a' before gravity.